# Send POST request in Google Apps Script with Headers and Body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send a POST request in order to receive an Access Token in return.

The documentation is as follows:

**Client Credentials**

This is your first route to obtain an access_token to communicate with the API.

Route : POST https://api.helloasso.com/oauth2/token

**Headers**

Content-Type =  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Body**

client_id   = Your Client Id

client_secret = Your Client Secret

grant_type =    client_credentials

**Solution I tried**

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154780/send-a-post-request-using-google-apps-script), I tried the following code:

```
function qwe()
{
  
  const url = 'https://api.helloasso.com/oauth2/token';

  const headers = { 
      "client_id": "Your Client Id",
      "client_secret": "Your Client Secret",
      "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    };

  const options = { 
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'headers': headers
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response);

  Logger.log(data);
  
}
```

Upon running this, I get an error "Exception: Request failed for https://api.helloasso.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"client_id is not set"}".

I am a beginner, and would appreciate any help on this! Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide the documentation for `https://api.helloasso.com` because this looks like it needs the Client ID to complete the authorization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of UrlFetchApp, the default content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- From your question and situation, I guessed that your `Body` might be required to be sent as form data.

If those points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function qwe() {
  const url = 'https://api.helloasso.com/oauth2/token';
  const data = {
    "client_id": "Your Client Id",
    "client_secret": "Your Client Secret",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
  };
  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText())
}
```

#### Note:

- If you tested this modified script, when an error occurs, please show the detailed error message and provide the official document. By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @lexiconkatu Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Need to make it stringify first

```
'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: I kiss your eyes <3