# How can I access a secondary email to retrieve subject line info?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am pretty novice when it comes to App Scripts and the entire OAuth process in general. I am working on a script that would be able to either read the Subject line information or the email itself(whichever is do-able),of a secondary email address with the Gmail API. From what I've read you need to set up OAuth configurations(which I think I have done correctly), After a bunch of messing around I was able to finally get a URL to appear to allow access, then more errors appeared. I finally got an error the says something about my script missing a function called "doGet". From reading similar cases I don't recall anyone mentioning a doGet function. I'm basically asking for advice or guidance to make sure I'm doing it right and not going the wrong way.

Once I changed a term in my script, I was able to get the URl to appear, I then went to that URl under the secondary account that I'm trying to use for the script. After getting URI redirect mismatch errors, I finally fixed that. I know get a "Script Function not found: doGet" error page, after I select "Allow" on the secondary email account.
From doing readings on similar situations, I don't recall a doGet function being used by other examples, So I don't know if I'm going the right direction or just going in circles.
I am now getting a a notice after I select allow, "the script has completed but did not return anything" It should be returning the subject info from the newest email.(edited 7/19/23)

```
function authorize() {
  var oauth2 = OAuth2.createService('Gmail')
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setScope(SCOPES.join(' '))
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force')
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback');

  var authorizationUrl = oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl();
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var oauth2 = OAuth2.createService('Gmail')
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setScope(SCOPES.join(' '))
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
  var authorized = oauth2.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    var accessToken = oauth2.getAccessToken();
    var threads = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('secondaryemailaccount.com', { accessToken: accessToken });
  } else {
    Logger.log('Authorization denied.');
  }
}
```

Comment: You have methold to retrive all thread and the in each thread you have getMessages() so you can go through all of the messages and pick the one's you wish

Comment: Not sure if you've figured this out or not, but `doGet` is usually referring to a web app. When you hit the deployed url of a Google Web App, Google expects there to be a `doGet` function. Is your redirect URI pointing to a deployed web app?

Comment: yes, i deployed the script as a web app and the redirect  uri is pointing back to the deployed script web app,
I also added a getMessage() as stated above and now after i select allow, a message comes back saying "The script completed but did not return anything" @MiguelRiveraRios

Comment: Gotcha, I definitely think your OAuth config is incorrect, for example, you should only need to create the OAuth service in your `authorize` method and not in the `authCallback`.  You can maybe find a more complete example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74031018/13771937). You can also find more on the official docs for the [OAuth library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2). If that still doesn't get you what you need, can you explain exactly what you want to happen and I can maybe help get you going.

Comment: Yes, let me see if I can get it based off that link you shared, and i will report back.

Comment: Also, what I'm trying to do is, retrieve the SUBJECT line info from a secondary email address via app script. that is all.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up just doing it the easy way, it works for my use case. I just made a new owner of the sheet/scripts by copying the information and making the secondary email address I need, the owner. I am able to get the information I need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).